# I need to add information to an already existing user in an XML file

Tags: php, html, xml

```
session_start();
$xml = simplexml_load_file('Gebruikers.xml');
$gebruiker = $xml->xpath('root[Login="'.$_SESSION['Login'].'"]');
$coordinates = $gebruiker[0]->addChild('coordinates');
$coordinates->addChild("X",$_GET["X"]);
$coordinates->addChild("Y",$_GET["Y"]);
file_put_contents('Gebruikers.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

XML-file

```
<root>
    <gebruiker>
        <Login>Tom</Login>
        <Wachtwoord>123</Wachtwoord>
    </gebruiker>
</root>
```

Getting these errors :

- Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tom\Project PHP\ProjectPHP_HTML\Coordinaten.php on line 6
- Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tom\Project PHP\ProjectPHP_HTML\Coordinaten.php on line 6

I'm so stuck .. please help me out.

Comment: For best results, please include a question in your post. Otherwise, we are required to attempt to deduce your intent, and the results are not always accurate.

Comment: Can you var_dump($gebruiker)? It's entirely possible your xpath is returning nothing. For the examples, rather than using `$_SESSION` try hard coding Tom since it's the only value we can see

Comment: I'm really sorry for this unclear representation of the problem but I'm just not sure what the problem is therefor i don't really know what information you would require to help me. But It's possible to make other 'gebruiker' elements therefor I can't hard code "Tom" because i need to be able to return another value if I log in with another account.

Answer (score 1):

the xpath for `$gebruiker` is wrong, do this instead:

```
$gebruiker = $xml->xpath('gebruiker[Login="'.$_SESSION['Login'].'"]');
```

What you did...

```
... xpath('root[Login="'.$_SESSION['Login'].'"]');
```

means: find a `<login>` node with the value as in `$_SESSION['login']` below `<root>`, but there is no such node, it is below `<gebruikers>`.

BTW, instead of `file_put_contents('Gebruikers.xml', $xml->asXML());`

you can do `$xml->asXML('myfile.xml');`

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9p2MYb

Comment: You are probably right :)